# Better class design

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, unreal-engine4

I am programming a game in Unreal Engine 4. The engine provides you several of class. In the question I will focus more on the connections of the classes rather than the purpose of them.

The engine's classes are like this (The "->" relates for inheritance. For example A -> B means that A inherits from B):
ACharacter -> APawn -> AActor -> ... -> UObject
The "..." is just unrelevent classes.
The UObject class is the main class of the engine, almost every class in the engine and in my game eventually inherites form UObject, In addition it provides many functions with I need.
The inheritance is **not** virtual inheritance. This will be important for the future. I can not edit any of the engine's classes.

On my game there are 3 main classes:
Buidling, Living and Entity.
Building inherits from **both** AActor and Entity
Living inherits from **both** ACharacter and Entity

[image]

I have created the Entity class to relates Building or Living without duplicating my code. For an example, the Living class needs to provide functionality of attacking another Living or Building. So I could just create 2 function of "AttackLiving" which has a Living target parameter and a fucntion "AttackBuilding" which has a Building target parameter, both function will have the exact same functionality. Instead I have created the Entity class so I would have just one function - "AttackEntity". Of course this is just one example, I use the Entity class all over the code so I can refer the Living and Building both in one shot.

The problems starts with the Entity class. I have made a mistake a year ago when I have actualy created it, I have not think this through. The problem is that Entity does not inherites from UObject. Again, the UObject class is main class of the engine and it provides many functions which I need. Because Entity does not inherites from UObject I can not access any of the functions which I need.

I can not make Entity inherites from UObject or AActor because virtual inheritance will not work here. (Again the engine classes inheritance is not virtual inheritance)

I have thought at number of possible solutions. One of them was that I can always down cast the Entity to Building or Living depends on the Entity's type, and than I can use the UObject's functions. But this is a very ugly  solution and it is contrasting the purpese of the Entity - not relate to Living and Building individualy.

Also I have thought on having a pointer in the Entity to the UObject class but agian this is a very ugly solution and it does not solve all of the problems. For an instance another problem with the Entity (which again does not inherits from UObject): There is a template class called "TWeakObjectPtr" which gets in a template a class, create a pointer for it and checks that the pointer is not freed anywhere else by the engine.

```
TWeakObjectPtr<Entity> entityPointer;
```

The problem is that TWeakObjectPtr checks that the class given in the templates inherites from UObject, and of course it is not so I can not use TWeakObjectPtr.

To conclude all this, the main problem is that Entity is not inherites from UObject. But I do need it so I can relate Living and Building together.

I would love if you can porpose a solution which keeps the Entity. Thanks in advance!

Comment: UObject is the base class of UE4. Everything must inherit from UObject. I would suggest reworking your Entity class to make this happen, otherwise I don't believe it will ever work.

Comment: Also, you may get a lot more help for this in the Game Development forums: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @ethancodes I know that, but I can not make it inherite form UObject becouse virtual inheritance will not work here. Do you have any actual solution for this problem?

Comment: yes, use interfaces or Actor Components.

Comment: @ethancodes I do not understand how is that going to help me. What do you mean interfaces? For which class? what actor components has to do in this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I've never used unreal engine, but hope some of the ideas below can be useful anyway.

One way to improve the situation is to break the inheritance link between two object hierarchies - yours and engine's:

```
UOjbect <-- AActor <-- APawn <-- ACharacter
               |                    |
+------+       *                    |
|      |<-- Building                |
|Entity|                            *
|      |<------------------------ Living
+------+
```

Where `*--` means aggregation (or composition).
Your classes do not inherit engine classes, instead they aggregate the appropriate engine object.

The `Entity` can have the virtual method `getUnreal()` that will return `UObject`, and subclasses will return `AActor` or `ACharacter` objects
appropriately.
So wherever you use `Entity`, you can get the engine object too, just not directly, but with `entiry->getUnreal()` call.

The other way around, you can inherit your classes from engine classes and make the "Entity" to be an aggregated behavior instead of base class:

```
UOjbect <-- AActor <-- APawn <-- ACharacter
               ^                    ^
+------+       |                    |
|      |--* Building                |
|Entity|                            |
|      |------------------------* Living
+------+
```

Here you would use your `Building` / `Living` where you need the engine object, but when you want to refer to your own logic, you will use something like `building->getEntity()`.
You may have different `Entity` sublclasses to implement `Building` and `Living` behavior.

Also I can recommend checking the `Design Patterns: Elements of Reusable Object-Oriented Software` book, the `Structural Patterns` chapter may help you finding more ideas.

Comment: Hey Boris, Thank you for you answer,  
The first solution does not solving the problem - Entity needs to inherite from UObject. I do not see how aggregation will solve this problem.
For the second solution - I do not think you have undrestood the purpose of Entity - Entity is an interface for Building and Living, if they will aggregate it instead of inherite from it the whole idea of Entity just will be pointless.  

I will look at this book. Thank you.